# SQL- FROM table-x WHERE table-y.field = variable. How does this get a distinct record from table-x?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am translating SQL stored procedures into C# Entity Framework. I am comfortable with C#, but SQL is pretty new to me. In one of the Stored Procedures, it begins with `select distinct`, then selects a bunch of table values and assigns them to variables. Then we get the `from where` portion, which is structured like below.

```
from
tableA

left outer join tableB on tableB.client = tableA.clientId
left outer join tableC tableCVar on tableC.client = tableA.clientId
left outer join tableD tableDVarX on tableD.client = tableA.cientId and tableD.ind = "X"
left outer join tableD tableDVarY on tableD.client = tableA.clientId and tableD.ind = "Y"

where tableB.client = @clientSSN and tableB.IdNumber = @tableBId and tableB.revisionNum = 1

END
```

QUESTION: How does the SQL know which record to select from **tableA** when its `where` statement is only looking at values related to **tableB**?

Am I missing something with how SQL works? I don't see how this query knows which tableA record is correct.

Comment: I believe you should try to get a basic understanding of how `joins` work. This article may help you: (http://www.sql-join.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from
tableA
left outer join tableB on tableB.client = tableA.clientId
where tableB.client = @clientSSN
```

"means" start with all tableA rows, then join every tableB row that matches, keeping tableA rows that have no matching tableB row.  The rows for tableA that have no matching tableB rows have NULLs for all the tableB columns in the result of the join.

BUT then putting a WHERE clause criterion on tableB filters out all the tableA rows that weren't matched.  So this becomes equivalent to an inner join.

```
from
tableA
inner join tableB on tableB.client = tableA.clientId
where tableB.client = @clientSSN
```

Answer (score 0):

The were clause is not only restricting the table on which the condition applied, since the tables are joined, it will filter all tables rows in fact.

Try to understand how the joins work: https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join